# Error with Javascript TypeError code, variable undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typeerror, var

I am trying to get the element with the ID `1a`, `2a`, `3a` etc. according to whenever the function is run.

It then compares that elements value (using jQuery) with the value of the `input` where the function is wrong
It brings up an error saying:

> TypeError: var1.toUpperCase is not a function. (in 'var2.toUpperCase()','var1.toUpperCase' is undefined)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
(UPDATE usually there would be text in questionNumber like: 1, 2, 3 etc every time the another function is run.)

---

EDIT: Every time a different function is run, `questionNumber` is increased by 1. I save `questionNumber`'s text in a variable called `word`. I then add the letter `a` to that variable. Then, I get the element that has ID of the variable `word`, then compare it's contents to the value of the `input`, but the comparison is uppercase to avoid problems. If they are equal, the `input` is replaced with a `div` with green text. Hope this makes it clearer.

```js
      function textVerify(item) {
          var word= document.getElementById(($('#questionNumber').text()+'a'));
      if (item.value.toUpperCase() === word.toUpperCase()){
          item.style.color = "green";
          $( item ).replaceWith( "<div style='color:green;'>"+word+"</div>" );
          main()
          } else {
              item.style.color = "black";
        }
```

```html
          <span class="ihide" id="questionNumber"></span>
          <p id="1a" class="ihide">Seven</p>
          <input id="1" name="Seven" type="text" value="" onkeyup="textVerify(this)" autofocus="">
```

Comment: What text do you have in `questionNumber` ? I see none

Comment: please add full javascript and explain what you're trying to achieve. What should happen when?

Comment: what is main()? And does the solution have to be in jquery or is vanilla js ok?

Comment: @TheHTMLCODERjs i've modified your code a little and fix the issue. Please check my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65159982/9340890) and let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var word` is `p` tag, so you need to get the inner text of it and compare it with the input text. Also, when replacing it, access the `text()` property of it. See below. `main()` is commented out here, but you can keep as per the need.

```js
function textVerify(item) {

  var word = document.getElementById(($('#questionNumber').text() + 'a'));

  if (item.value.toUpperCase() === $(word).text().toUpperCase()) {
    item.style.color = "green";
    $(item).replaceWith("<div style='color:green;'>" + $(word).text() + "</div>");
    //main()
  } else {
    item.style.color = "black";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ihide" id="questionNumber">1</span>
<p id="1a" class="ihide">Seven</p>
<input id="1" name="Seven" type="text" value="" onkeyup="textVerify(this)" autofocus="">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `($('#questionNumber').text()+'a')` this part returns just 'a', as text of the id `questionNumber` is nothing.

And in your HTML there is no such id. I think you need to make this changes to your HTML code:

`<span class="ihide" id="questionNumber">1</span>`

This should work.

EDIT: Also, can you please share the JS code associated with 'item', there can be an error in that part too.

Comment: I'm sorry to point it out, but can someone please explain where am I wrong? @Pirate can you? I am a bit confused.

Comment: you're partially right about the text being empty by looking at the html. I had the same doubt, but op said it will be populated by JavaScript,so there will actually be something. Ultimately, that code will return 1a, 2a and so on. However, it will still not work because of few incorrect use of JavaScript and jquery methods. Check my answer for fix in js function op has. It's working there.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for clarifying, got your point @Pirate.